# Using AWS CLI - Bad Credential Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-cli

I am attempting to setup some custom CloudWatch metrics using [mon-put-data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/cli/cli-mon-put-data.html) from within my AWS EC2 instance. According to the documentation I am using it correctly.

```
mon-put-data --namespace Layer --metric-name ResponseTime --dimensions "app=AppName" --value 2
```

However, when I run it I get the following error:

`mon-put-data:  Malformed input-Bad credentials in file: /user/.aws/credentials [keyId: null | secretKey null]`

The Format of the credentials file is below and was auto generated using `aws configure`

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = KJHJKHJKHJKHJKHJKHJK
aws_secret_access_key = KHKJJKHJKHJKHJH123123kjhjkhjk12312
```

I have also confirm that the `AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE` path exists and is correct. Also, I have confirmed that the IAM User has full access to CloudWatch and EC2.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: A few things to check: are the credentials correct? Have you tried setting the environment variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and tried running the CLI again? It will read from the environment before it tries to read from the credentials files.

Comment: @birryree thanks for the suggestion. I just tried that. Same issue.

Comment: @Yonkee can you check if you access key is active in IAM?

Comment: Can you try running mon-put-data with `--aws-credential-file <full-path-to-cred-file>` ?

Comment: @helloV I tried that first before adding the env variable. Unfortunately the same issue. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I just realized you were using a different CLI tool from the standard `aws` CLI tool, so I think my answer should be the one you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working with the addition of the -I and -S options. Not really ideal have the credentials inline, but it works for now.

```
mon-put-data -I <Key ID> -S <Secret Key> --namespace Layer --metric-name ResponseTime --dimensions "app=AppName" --value 2
```

Obviously mon-put-data command uses a credential file that has a different format to the one created by `AWS CLI.` Unfortunately there is nothing in the documentation to define it and I can't find the code to debug it.

Answer (score 1):

I originally misread your question and thought you were using the [actual AWS CLI tool](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/), which uses the INI-style format like you posted:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = KJHJKHJKHJKHJKHJKHJK
aws_secret_access_key = KHKJJKHJKHJKHJH123123kjhjkhjk12312
```

However, when you use `mon-put-data`, it doesn't follow any of the configuration or options from the CLI.

For the service-specific CLIs (like Cloudwatch tools), you have to setup the tool as detailed [on this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/cli/SetupCLI.html#CW_Generic_GSG_Configure).

You have to generate a file of this format:

```
AWSAccessKeyId=<Write your AWS access ID>
AWSSecretKey=<Write your AWS secret key>
```

Then you have to pass `--aws-credential-file` as your argument, or set the environment variable `AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE`.

If you were using the standard all-in-one AWS CLI, you could do the exact same thing as `mon-put-data` by using [`aws.cloudwatch.put-metric-data`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/put-metric-data.html).